# moving data to core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, sqlite

i have a .sqlite file with all the data i want to be used with my iPhone app .

but i feel i should be using Core data for what i want done.

is it possible to some how move all the data that is held within my .sqlite file to core data's .sqlite file ?

i have created only 2 fields in my .sqlite file and 2 attributes in the core data file, but i don't think i can replace the coreData's sqlite file as core data added additional fields to it.

what is the best way to handle this .

thanks

Comment: Where does your sqlite database come from? Did you generate it, or is it being provided to you somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you generated the database yourself, the best way to move the data into a Core Data store is to use Core Data itself to re-generate the data. You can do this either through a throw-away app or within your app itself.

The fact that Core Data on the iPhone uses SQLite as a backing store is an implementation detail. Trying to recreate the core data store yourself may to cause very obscure bugs, you'll be much safer by allowing Core Data to generate the database.

@ExtremeCoder's answer is an option, but even writing an app to read from SQLite and store into Core Data would be a better choice than what that blog suggests.

Comment: Ok so i read in the data from the sqlite file and keep storing it in the core data, right ?

Comment: You only need to do it once. Read all the data in, store it using CoreData, then you're done.

Comment: How are you generating the data?

Comment: the data is meant to be read only so i generated it manually. so i guess That is the best way ....
i was hoping for a standard applications that would make any sqlite db into core data .
thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://ablogontech.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/using-a-pre-populated-sqlite-database-with-core-data-on-iphone-os-3-0/